# Mysql search interprets european character as non-european character

Tags: mysql

When I do a search on a string containing the letter "a", that letter also matches words containing the letter "ä" and "å".

So if I search for "anna" it matches a text containing "känna". If I search for "manda" it matches "månda".

The database character set is:  `latin1`
The table character set: `utf8mb4`

I can test it by searching a particular row and a particular column:

```
SELECT * FROM events AS e  
WHERE e.content LIKE '%anna%' AND e.id = 1230
```

That would return that row (1230). If I remove the line containing "känna" from the "content" column of that row, there will be no match. So it interprets all european characters based on "a" as also being "ä", or "å".

How do I correct this?

**edit**:

okay, here is a fiddle:
[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2445bd/1)

**Show create table events output:** (I removed some columns):

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
 `event_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1242 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: *"How do I correct this?"* We can't tell because SQL is declarative language. SQL servers makes more processing and compiling under the hood.. Because off that we don't know how a query without table  structure and example data will run we can only make educated geusses . See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results..

Comment: *"So it interprets all european characters based on "a" as also being "ä", or "å"."* A educated geuss would be to change the `COLLATE` on [runtime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-literal.html) or change it in the [table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-column.html) to a non binary one.. Ideally you should show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE events` output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the character set and collate for your literal:

```
SELECT * FROM events AS e  
WHERE e.content LIKE _utf8mb4 '%anna%' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci AND e.id = 1230
```